# Creating 1D array from two 1D arrays with condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am running this program:

```
def f2d(x,y):
    # condition
    if 4*x**2 + y**2 <= 4:
        return np.sin(x*y)
    else:
        return 0

def my_prog(function,n):
    x = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=+1, size=(n))
    y = np.random.uniform(low=-2, high=+2, size=(n))
    f = function(x,y)
    return (f,n)

(f,n) = my_prog(f2d,5)
```

and I get this error:
`The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

It's not very clear: I don't understand how I could insert `a.any()` or `a.all()` within the program I made, where should I do it, and why...

My goal was just to have `f` created as a 1D array (just as `x` and `y` are 1D arrays) and containing `np.sin(x*y)` if condition is fulfilled, or `0` if condition is not fulfilled, as requested in `def f2d(x,y)`?
So, it looks like a kind of element wise manipulation of arrays `x` and `y` under a certain condition. But I can't see why it doesn't work. Should I first create `f` as an empty array? Does the problem come from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if-clause is expecting a truthy-value but `4*x**2 + y**2 <= 4` is shape (5,) boolean array. To get it to work, you should either convert it to a single truthy-value or iterate over it, depending on what you're trying to do. However, for the purpose of your task, you could use `numpy.where` to select values depending on the condition. In this case, select from `np.sin(x*y)` if the condition is satisfied, 0 otherwise.

```py
def f2d(x,y):
    # condition
    return np.where(4*x**2 + y**2 <= 4, np.sin(x*y), 0)
```

Test run:

```py
>>> my_prog(f2d,5)
(array([0.02896101, 0.34900898, 0.        , 0.        , 0.15721751]), 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is under `# condition`, after comparing the operation result with 4, you will get a Boolean array, but the Boolean array cannot be converted to a true value, so you get an error, like this:

```
>>> np.arange(8) < 5
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False])
>>> if np.arange(8) < 5:
...     pass
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```